# VSCode extension API: simple local Quick Diff

Tags: version-control, vscode-extensions

Trying to understand how to implement simple source control management in my language extension.
I need to show a Quick Diff for a single file (my extension doesn't work with folders) compared with some special one.
Let's say i have this `TextDocumentContentProvider` and `QuickDiffProvider`:

```js
class MyLangDocumentContentProvider implements vscode.TextDocumentContentProvider
{
    provideTextDocumentContent(uri: vscode.Uri)
    {
        return getFileText(uri); // returns text of provided file uri
    }
}

class MyLangRepository implements vscode.QuickDiffProvider
{
    provideOriginalResource(uri: vscode.Uri)
    {
        return getOriginalFileUri(uri); // returns uri of the special file to compare with
    }
}
```

Then in `activate` method of extension i initialize them:

```js
const docProvider = new MyLangDocumentContentProvider();
const gitSCM = vscode.scm.createSourceControl('git', 'Git');
gitSCM.quickDiffProvider = new MyLangRepository();
const workingTree = gitSCM.createResourceGroup('workingTree', 'Changes');
workingTree.resourceStates = [
    { resourceUri: vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri }
];
```

Then i need to call `registerTextDocumentContentProvider` with some custom uri scheme. So why do i need custom uri scheme? And what else should i do to track changes of current file relative to the special one?

I was looking at `vscode-extension-samples/source-control-sample`, but it looks more complicated then my case.

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 0):

Though my question was rather sily, let me save here some kind of instruction, how I've done this.

1. to make `QuickDif` work you don't need neither `ResourceGroups` nor `TextDocumentContentProvider`, this is a separate functionality.
2. `SourceControl` (and also its quickDiffProvider) will work if you pass some root directory in constructor (I've got no luck without thoug I don't need it for my purpose).